# JavaScript to Pass variable and retrieve output from PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Trying to pass a variable to a PHP file then get the output of that file.

Page1.html:

```
 <h2 id="test"></h2>
 <script>
 var data2;
 $.post('textandemail.php',{ txt: "John", email: "test@gmail.com" },
  function(data) {
 data2 = data;});
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data2;
 </script>
```

textandemail.php:

```
  $variable = $_POST["txt"];
  $variable2 = $_POST["email"];
  echo $variable;
  echo $variable2;
```

Hopefully this describes the desired idea. I will be doing much more in the PHP file but in the end echoing out a response that I want the JavaScript to read and implement into the html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.post()` function is asynchronous.  It finishes some time LATER.  You need to put the assignment of the results from that function into the success handler, not after the function itself because as you have it now, the line `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data2;` is occurring BEFORE the ajax function has finished and thus it won't work.

This is how you can do it:

```
<h2 id="test"></h2>
 <script>
 $.post('textandemail.php',{ txt: "John", email: "test@gmail.com" },
    function(data) {
       // any code that uses the ajax results in data must be here
       // in this function or called from within this function
       document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data;
    }
  );
 </script>
```

Or, since you have jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
<h2 id="test"></h2>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script>
 $.post('textandemail.php',{ txt: "John", email: "test@gmail.com" },
    function(data) {
       // any code that uses the ajax results in data must be here
       // in this function or called from within this function
       $("#test").html(data);
    }
  );
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! the java script is not working...I get nothing put in between h2 tag... trying the jQuery now

Comment: Ahh silly me commented out a big block that included the script src for jquery... ahhhh....woshhhhh back to work..... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your post call is asynchronous, you have access to the `data2` variable only once the process is done, so you should do your `....innerHTML ...` in the callback function, when the data  is available, not before.

There are plenty of good examples of this on any js sites. On the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) you have a good example.
Since you are useing jQuery, you could replace your `innerHTML` call too.

Answer (score 1):

you should use ajax function to make communication between php and javascript

```
 function Ajax_Send(GP,URL,PARAMETERS,RESPONSEFUNCTION){
var xmlhttp
try{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")}
catch(e){
try{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
catch(e){
try{xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()}
catch(e){
alert("Your Browser Does Not Support AJAX")}}}

err=""
if (GP==undefined) err="GP "
if (URL==undefined) err +="URL "
if (PARAMETERS==undefined) err+="PARAMETERS"
if (err!=""){alert("Missing Identifier(s)\n\n"+err);return false;}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
if (RESPONSEFUNCTION=="") return false;
eval(RESPONSEFUNCTION(xmlhttp.responseText))
}
}

if (GP=="GET"){
URL+="?"+PARAMETERS
xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,true)
xmlhttp.send(null)
}

if (GP="POST"){
PARAMETERS=encodeURI(PARAMETERS)
xmlhttp.open("POST",URL,true)
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length",PARAMETERS.length)
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
xmlhttp.send(PARAMETERS)
```

the call functions put it inside the javascript page

```
Ajax_Send("POST","users.php",data,e)
```

where data is the data you send to the php page and e is the function you pass the output of php page to it